# How to create hide-return values on a function, so they are only returned when called?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, return

Say I have a function whose output is `a,b`.

I would like to have the same function that either returns `a` or `a,b` depending if I call `b` specifically (for the later case).

Is there any way to write such kind of function in Python?

Answer (score 5):

Sure you can. It's a *bad idea*, but nothing stops you from returning a tuple when a flag is set:

```
def foo(add_b=False):
    if add_b:
        return a, b

    return a
```

It's better not to do this; you are changing the type of object returned here. It'd be better if you added a *new* function instead:

```
def foo_with_b():
    return a, b

def foo_without_b():
    return foo_with_b()[0]
```

or just account for the extra return item returned and simply ignore it, which is what `foo_without_b()` is doing, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to do, but probably a bad idea.

```
def myfn(x, y, b_also=False):
    a = x + y
    b = x - y
    return (a,b) if b_also else a
```